# Error: No value given for one or more required parameters. What does this mean? How do I fix?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm creating a program in which users can see a table from an access database in a DataGridView.

However, when pressing "btnDisplay" the program crashes and highlights this line:

```
da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
```

The error reads: "No value given for one or more required parameters"

What does this mean and how do I fix it?
Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmViewTables
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    Private Sub btnDisplayDataGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayDataGrid.Click

        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tblOrders] where Username = @username", MyConn)

        cm.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, frmLogin.SuccessfulLoginUsername))

        cm.Parameters("@username").Value = frmLogin.SuccessfulLoginUsername

        da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        dgvDynamic.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

Comment: It means no value was given for a parameter.  Since there is just one, that *should* narrow it down for you.  The last arg to the New OleDbParameter is probably not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things seem a little messed up. I am not sure about the rest of it but this should solve your parameter problem.

```
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
        Dim ds = New DataSet
        Dim tables = ds.Tables
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb")
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [tblOrders] where Username = @username", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = frmLogin.SuccessfulLoginUsername
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        dgvDynamic.DataSource = view
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked exactly the way I wanted it to. Was the cmd.parameters.add line format all messed up which is what caused the error? Thank you!

Comment: That was part of it but also I don't see where the command was ever associated with the DataAdapter. The line da.SelectCommand = cmd fixed that problem.